# File not found on local testing server

Tags: php

Have downloaded Dreamweaver 20.1. Am trying to set up a local testing server on my Mac running 10.14.6. Have followed Adobe's instructions on creating a PHP developer environment, and have checked the MAMP instructions as well. I can't seem to get even the simple time test file to run, never mind the test site - I keep getting the warning that "This page my have dynamically-related files that can only be discovered by the server.", and in Live View, the message: "Not Found", and "The requested URL /php_test/timetest.php was not found on this server." I have scanned my ports and they're not blocked, and MAMP indicates that both the MySQL and Apache servers are running.

Comment: It seems that your configuration for local in the Adobe Dreamweaver has some problem, first of all, provide more information in your question to be clear. and instead of live view in software check your URL address in browser e.g http://localhost/php_test/timetest.php (php_test should be in your MAMP root directory) id it is ok, something in your software configuration is wrong.

Comment: I managed to find a different article that showed how to set up the folders properly, so I now have PHP running successfully. However, I am unable to now connect to the MySQL database. I can't find the "Database" tab or window in Dreamweaver 20.1 (most documents suggest it's in the "Window" menu), and cannot find support documents or tutorials to help me find it.

Comment: Check this video that shows how to config the database in the Dreamweaver. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVK4z_SgsYE

Comment: That's the thing - it's for DW vCSx. Version 20.1 doesn't have the same window available to connect the database. All instructions seem to say go to the "Window" menu and open the Database pane... there is no Database pane in v20.1's Window menu.

Comment: You should add an alternative extension for new versions. check this one for example https://www.dmxzone.com/go/23295/dmxzone-server-connect/?utm_source=extension&utm_medium=link&utm_content=Enable+Server+Behaviors+and+Data+Bindings+Panel+Support+for+Dreamweaver+CC+&utm_campaign=DMXzone+Server+Connect

Comment: This is a paid extension. Is there anything that can help connecting DreamWeaver to a database that is no charge? Trying to manage cash flow in isolation and this is a low-priority project. If we need to buy a program for future use we will when we're back up and running.

Comment: In my point of view, there is no need for this kind of visual connection, If you use an appropriate SQL documentation or guide you can easily work with your needed data query. All in all, if you are going to use an alternative solution, you can search for visual SQL query tools, probably you will find a free extension or visual tools. e.g. https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/best-sql-query-builders/

Comment: I don't know that I need a discrete and separate query tool, actually. I just have to integrate the web design with Dreamweaver, as I'm most familiar with that tool. Unfortunately, this new version of DW hasn't made it easy to find where to link databases.